# Intent (activity) skipping

Tags: android

I had an app that i want it exit a specific activity for example:
A -> B -> C
but everytime i press the back button from activity C it always bring me back to B and from B to A before exiting. Is there anyway that I can exit directly from C no need to go through B and A again?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know A and B are complete, call `finish()` within each of them after they've started the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an Activity to show up in the history, you can define it in the manifest file with the noHistory attribute.  I've done this for a few of my activities.

```
<activity android:name="com.sample.activity.MyActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
```